# Why is my Javascript code not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently started working with Javascript, like a few hours ago, and I can't figure out why it's still showing text it shouldn't be on my website.  Dreamweaver says no error, but there has to be..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var day = new Date();
     var hr = day.getHours();
     if((hr == 1) || (hr == 2) || (hr == 3) || (hr == 4) || (hr == 5) || (hr == 6) || (hr == 7) || (hr == 8) || (hr == 9)); {
         document.write("Paragraph one stack example");
     }
    if(hr == 10) {
        document.write("P2 stack ex");
    }
    if((hr == 11) || (hr == 12) || (hr == 13)); {
        document.write("P3 stack ex.");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Also, please shorten your `if` statement to `if (hr >= 1 && hr <= 9)`.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, slightly reformatted:

```
if((hr == 1) || ... || (hr == 9)); {
    document.write("Paragraph one stack example");
}
```

Get rid of that semicolon, it's making the entire `if` bit irrelevant.

What it translates to is:

```
if((hr == 1) || ... || (hr == 9))
    ;
{
    document.write("Paragraph one stack example");
}
```

In other words,

- if `hr` is 1-9, do nothing.
- regardless of the value of `hr`, output "Paragraph one stack example".

You have the same problem with the `if` statement for `11/12/13` as well.

---

A *better* solution for that "one through nine" `if` statement, by the way, would be:

```
if((hr >= 1) && (hr <= 9)) {
    document.write("Paragraph one stack example");
}
```

and you can further clean up the code since all the conditions are mutually exclusive:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var day = new Date();
    var hr = day.getHours();
    if ((hr >= 1) || (hr <= 9)) {
        document.write("Paragraph one stack example");
    } else if (hr == 10) {
        document.write("P2 stack ex");
    } else if ((hr >= 11) && (hr <= 13)) {
        document.write("P3 stack ex.");
    }
</script>
```

There's little point checking if `hr` is equal to `10` if you've already established that it's `4`, for example. So you can use `else if` for that.

Comment: You have a semicolon after the if statement, that stops it in its tracks.  Remove this and I'm sure it will work.

Comment: Sorry it's early here haven't woken up...I put my answer in the wrong place, regards

Answer (score 1):

Code is valid, but you have done mistake when put

> ;

at the end of if expression

if you remove this all will works fine!

```js
var day = new Date();
var hr = day.getHours();
if((hr == 1) || (hr == 2) || (hr == 3) || (hr == 4) || (hr == 5) || (hr == 6) || (hr == 7) || (hr == 8) || (hr == 9)) {
  document.write("Paragraph one stack example");
}
if(hr == 10) {
  document.write("P2 stack ex");
}
if((hr == 11) || (hr == 12) || (hr == 13)) {
  document.write("P3 stack ex.");
}
```